# Correct settings for nVidia current driver to make work dual monitor setup as extended desktop (not twinview)

Tags: nvidia, 11.10, multiple-monitors, twinview

I have an Asus 22" widescreen monitor with resolution: 1680x1050, and another Samsung 19" with resolution: 1280*1024.
I use my Asus as primary display, and want to use my Samsung monitor as streched desktop, but when I activate the secondary display, it works only in twinview mode (it works correct). But when I try to use it in separate X mode, in different resolution, all the things (Unity launcher, gnome panel (top bar), and window borders) missing. If I restart the system (only reset works) the login screen appears, but can't login, because the loginscreen freezes after typing password and hitting enter. I can login with Ubuntu 2D.
Without closed nVidia drivers the extended desktop mode works correct (under display menu).
Is there any way to make it work? What did i wrong?
I'm using nVidia 9600GT in my system, with Ubuntu 11.10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-settings/+bug/882143)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, I experience the same. But using "Twinview" option does the opposite (extended).

Give this a try and if this is the case, then nVidia has something to do with this. Or is it an Ubuntu related issue?

Here you can see my `nvidia-settings` monitors arrangement with the "Twinview" configured but as you can notice in the screenshot, my desktop is extended.

[image]

BTW: I don't know how can this be fixed or if possible. But it works this way and it is good for me.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wonder if it works at different resolutions. I'll give a try again, but i've noticed, with Twinview option switched on, i have Unity menu on each screen, and top menu as well, looks like i'm having clone mode switched.

Comment: Reinstalled closed drivers, and it seems to work with your workaround. Thank you. (I have two top menus each screen, this is a little bit weird.)